# Why cant slice or something like that of my arrays with php

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, multidimensional-array

I have lot arrays and i want to only print number of 2 and first arrays
i use `array_slice` but there is still a problem

Arrays:

```
Array
(
[0] => 441
[1] => Awesome
)
Array
(
[0] => 570
[1] => Noons
)
Array
(
[0] => 571
[1] => Roods
)
```

I need to like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 441
[1] => Awesome
)
Array
(
[0] => 570
[1] => Noons
)
```

Comment: whats the problem??

Comment: `but there is still a problem`-> what problem?

Comment: `print ($finalarray);` will prints `Array`, not the array content. Do you mean `print_r()` ?

Comment: @Syscall Yes print_R

Comment: Problem is : I cant print only 2 of first arrays

Comment: set `$counter =1;`

Comment: or use `print_r(array_slice($Myarray,0,2))`

Comment: what do you print now??

Comment: OUT : Array
(
[0] => 441
[1] => Awesome
)
Array
(
[0] => 570
[1] => Noons
)
Array
(
[0] => 571
[1] => Roods
)

Comment: Does not do anything?????

Comment: you have two print_r in your question, which one you are trying and which one you are showing values here?? please re-check as there is no problem in your code it sees

Comment: This may be nitpicky but why do you do an array unique after each merge instead of a single one at the end? Check out what happened to [Shlemiel](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter)

Comment: @Sohel0415 Updated mr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you seem to only need:

```
array_slice(array_unique(array_column($Myarrays, 'nidtitle')), 0, 2);
```

This should be done instead of the entire code you use to generate the arrays.

Short explanation:

1. `array_column` will get the element `nidtitle` from each "row" (array entry) in `$Myarrays`
2. After that we run that column through a unique function
3. Then we get the first 2 elements with an `array_slice`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
$finalarray = array_slice($Myarray, 0, 2);
print_r($finalarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_slice to get the items you want.

```
$arr = array(Array(441,"Awesome"),
Array(570,"Noons"),
Array(571,"Roods"));

$two = array_slice($arr, 0,2);
Var_dump($two);
```

Array_slice second parameter is where the slice should start.
Third parameter is count of values to slice.

https://3v4l.org/NPcJT